# Android Alert Dialog - how to hide the OK button after it being pressed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have been developing an Android app.

I would like to hide the OK button after the user presses it, as the dialog window will stay at the foreground for some seconds while a computation takes place.

This is the code:

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("This may take a while")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       // hide the OK button - how?
                       // a lot of computation
        }
    })
    .show();
```

How can I achieve that?

P.S.: I am not interesting to more advanced techniques to handle a computation (such as: progress dialogs, multi-threading).

Thanks.

Comment: If you're intending to do a long-running computation on the UI thread, prepare for your users giving you lots of negative feedback when your app triggers application not responding errors.

Comment: To prevent "application not responding" errors, you should run your computation in an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
.setPositiveButton("OK", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(which).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         // the rest of your stuff
    }
})
```

Comment: However it looks like your design is not perfect in this part. Probably it would be better to use `AsyncTask` with `ProgressDialog`. AsyncTask allows to run long computations on a background thread so your main UI thread is not blocked and thus the app will not get an ANR.

Comment: Is there a way of disabling the button depends on a textfield on the dialog bar?

Comment: @akdurmus: I believe there should be a way, however please ask a new question on this.

Comment: Instead of making it disappear, I would just disable it. `.setEnabled( false )` It is less **jarring** for the user. Also, certainly use an `AlertDialog` inside of `ASyncTask` instead of just an `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 1):

```
setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        dialog.dismiss();
```

where `dialog` is `DialogInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else trying to disable the Positive button on an `AlertDialog`, a lot of these solutions don't seem to work now - you can't grab a reference to the button as soon as you call `create` on the `AlertDialog.Builder`, it'll just return null.

So one place it should be available is in `onResume`, so the way I got this to work was something like this:

```
var positiveButton: Button? = null

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (positiveButton == null) {
        positiveButton = (dialog as AlertDialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
    }
}
```

and that way you should have a reference available whenever your fragment is running, so you can just call `positiveButton.isEnabled = false` whenever you need to disable it.

Just be careful with your state, a recreated fragment might have some checked boxes or whatever, but it won't have that `positiveButton` reference yet, and it'll re-run that code in `onResume`. So if you need to do any initialisation (like disabling the button until the user selects an option) make sure you call a function that checks the current state and decides whether the button should be enabled or not. Don't assume it's just starting up blank!

Answer (score -3):

You can set the visibility of button to invisible.

```
ok.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: but how can I get the 'ok' variable?