# How to disable / enable dialog negative positive buttons?

Tags: android, button, dialog

Please look at  the custom dialog below. I have an edittext field on the dialog and if the text field is empty I would like to disable the `positiveButton`. I can get a charListener for the text field but I am not sure how I am going to set the `positivebutton` to disable or enable from that listener? What is the reference for the positive and negative buttons?

```
 case DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY:
    // This example shows how to add a custom layout to an AlertDialog
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogSamples.this)
        .setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
        .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_text_entry)
        .setView(textEntryView)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
            }
        })
        .create();
}
```

Comment: I think this answer answers your question 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291548/android-alert-dialog-how-to-hide-the-ok-button-after-it-being-pressed][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291548/android-alert-dialog-how-to-hide-the-ok-button-after-it-being-pressed

Comment: thanks but this is not the answer. it might help though. because it disable the button after clicking itself. which is not what I want. I would like to show it disabled depends on the textfield.

Comment: if(editTextEmailAddress.getText().toString().length()==0)

Comment: Basically you are making an object with anonymous reference once it is created you can't reference it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

***Edit for complete solution...***

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
builder.setTitle("Alert dialog title");
builder.setMessage("This is the example code snippet to disable button if edittext attached to dialog is empty.");
builder.setPositiveButton("PositiveButton",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // DO TASK
            }
        });
builder.setNegativeButton("NegativeButton",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // DO TASK
            }
        });

// Set `EditText` to `dialog`. You can add `EditText` from `xml` too.
final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
);
input.setLayoutParams(lp);


builder.setView(input);

final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();

// Initially disable the button
((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);

// OR you can use here setOnShowListener to disable button at first time.

// Now set the textchange listener for edittext
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // Check if edittext is empty
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            // Disable ok button
            ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);

        } else {
            // Something into edit text. Enable the button.
            ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
        }

    }
});
```

---

> Below are edited history, which can be refer as some more details

***Here is a sample code, try this***

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddSchedule.this);
builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
builder.setTitle("Alert dialog title");
builder.setMessage("Dialog message");
builder.setPositiveButton("Button1", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        //DO TASK
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Button2", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        //DO TASK
    }
});

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();

// After calling show method, you need to check your condition and enable/disable the dialog buttons 
if (your_condition_true) {
    // BUTTON1 is the positive button
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON1).setEnabled(false);
}
```

*For negative button*

```
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON2).setEnabled(false); //BUTTON2 is negative button
```

**For buttons id** : *Reference* [alert_dialog.xml](http://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml?r=44)

**Edited :**

***And the [setOnShowListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnShowListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnShowListener%29) since level 8 API (FroYo), does the same,***

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        if (condition) {
            ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});

dialog.show();
```

---

**Edited**

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setMessage("This may take a while")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(which).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // the rest of your stuff
        }

    }).show();
```

---

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but when you again called AlertDialog is it called its object again or still it using same one. I am not aware of this method .should you explain in brief? Thanks:)

Comment: For skimmers I'd like to add that dialog.getButton() only works for AlertDialogs, so you may have to cast the dialog to AlertDialog as you do farther down in the post.

Comment: don't work - also I read code at least 5x, and it still doesn't make sense why it should work :) Correct answer is below from Nick Palmer

Comment: @qkx Can you explain what you are trying to do. Can you show the relevant code? And don't be ironic and do downvote.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I didn't want to be ironic ;) Simple - onShow method is called only once, so enabling/disabling OK button here doesn't make any sense, as it will be done only once. If I understood question well, akdurmus wanted to have OK button disabled until he write something into edit text. Which means there MUST be listener on edit text (when empty OK button will be disabled, otherway nabled) - no other solution is possible. In my opinion Nick Palmer below has the right solution. Or I didn't get it - can be :)

Comment: @qkx : too genius you are. Read carefully I have added `if(your_condition_true)` and then enable disable the button. You said you tried my solution and not worked. Can you share your code? And you are with another answer then can you say me what is `d` in his code?? You did tried??? :D

Comment: I copy pasted your code (code section 1) and also added onShowListener. However, regardless of code, onShow method is called only ONCE and never ever again. So whatever condition is here, it will be called onces and so OK button eanability won't be changed again. For example if you have firstly EditText empty, when creating dialog condition will be let's say true and OK button will be disabled. This is ok for now, however if you type something into edit text, onShow method won't be called again - so OK button won't be enabled...I hope I explained it better.

Comment: d is dialog, he forgot 1 line - d = builder.create () :))

Comment: @qkx Do you know what does `if(your_condition_true)
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON1).setEnabled(false);` means? Put that code block into the text change listener. Look I am not here for teaching you. If you can not understand its your problem. And you can do downvote too because this is your right. But think many times if you are saying that someone's answer is wrong.

Comment: I didn't want to be ironic, rude. Also I tried to un-downvote but it is not possible...However once again to the problem - where do you have text listener in your code, can you tell me? It doesn't matter what the condition is, if it is called only once. If you do not have text listener like Nick below, it is simple impossible for your solution to work...Or I missed something. Or send me some simple android project to prove it is working ;)

Comment: @qkx I am not here to prove myself. If you think answer is not correct your welcome.

Comment: I just wanted to say to other users, that this code can't be working because there is no text listener, what is necessary condition. I didn't want to harm anybody, nor you. Anyway, it has no meaning to continue our "discussion"...Have a nice day

Comment: Thank you!!! I wanted this one: "((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);" you really helped me thanks a lot :))

Comment: This answer would be easier to understand if all the edits were combined into a single solution.

Answer (score 27):

None of these answers really solve the problem.

I accomplish this using a custom layout with an EditText in it and a TextWatcher on that view.

```
final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.text_dialog, null);
final EditText text = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_edit);
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);
// Now add the buttons...
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
    // Left out for brevity...
}
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
    // Left out for brevity...
}

// Create the dialog
final AlertDialog d = builder.create();

// Now add a TextWatcher that will handle enable/disable of save button
text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    private void handleText() {
        // Grab the button
        final Button okButton = d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        if(text.getText().length() == 0) {
            okButton.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            okButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        handleText();
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Nothing to do
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       // Nothing to do
    }
});

// show the dialog
d.show();
// and disable the button to start with
d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete, there is no declaration of `d`

Comment: Edited to add construction of d.

Answer (score 5):

Here is complete code to enable and disable positive button of dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);

builder.setView(view);
builder.setTitle("Test");
builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ok clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", null);

final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

alertDialog.show();

EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.mobile_number);
alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.length() >= 1) {
            alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a listener to the edit text box, and try to enable or disable buttons. This is a sample code for xamarin.

```
var dialog = builder.Create();

dialog.Show();

var btnOk = dialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive).Enabled = false;

_enterTextDialogEditText.AfterTextChanged += (sender, e) => {
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_enterTextDialogEditText.Text)) {
    dialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive).Enabled = true;
  } else {
    dialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive).Enabled = false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For delete record from database list view using view holder you used this code in your getview() method..

> viewHolder.btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Favorate.this.getParent());

                    // Setting Dialog Title
                    alertDialog2.setTitle("Confirm Delete...");

                    // Setting Dialog Message
                    alertDialog2
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want delete ?");

                    // Setting Icon to Dialog
                    alertDialog2.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

                    // Setting Positive "Yes" Btn
                    alertDialog2.setPositiveButton("YES",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // Write your code here to execute after
                                    // dialog

                                    int id = _items.get(position).id;
                                    db.deleterecord(id);

                                    db.close();
                                }
                            });
                    // Setting Negative "NO" Btn
                    alertDialog2.setNegativeButton("NO",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // Write your code here to execute after
                                    // dialog

                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    // Showing Alert Dialog
                    alertDialog2.show();

                }
            });
```

[Read More](http://androidroadies.blogspot.in/2013/09/alert-dialog-with-delete-yes-or-no.html)

Answer (score 0):

This dialogFragment will do the job for you. Note that the dialog will remain open after screen rotation preserving any text that the user has already typed in. If you don't want that to happen you need to dismiss the fragment in your activity's onStop. The newInstance method signature can be changed to whatever you need.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TextViewDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener, DialogInterface.OnShowListener, TextWatcher
{
    final static private String TITLE = "title", MESSAGE = "message", IDENTIFIER = "identifier", INPUT_TYPE = "inputType", POSITIVE_TEXT = "pText", NEGATIVE_TEXT = "nText", CANCELABLE = "cancelable";

    public TextViewDialogFragment()
    {
        super();
    }

    static public TextViewDialogFragment newInstance(int title, @Nullable String message, int identifier, int inputType, int positiveText, int negativeText, boolean cancelable)
    {
        TextViewDialogFragment fragement = new TextViewDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(TITLE, title);
        args.putString(MESSAGE, message);
        args.putInt(IDENTIFIER, identifier);
        args.putInt(INPUT_TYPE, inputType);
        args.putInt(POSITIVE_TEXT, positiveText);
        args.putInt(NEGATIVE_TEXT, negativeText);
        args.putBoolean(CANCELABLE, cancelable);
        fragement.setArguments(args);
        return fragement;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Activity activity =  getActivity();
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        EditText input = new EditText(activity);
        input.setInputType(args.getInt(INPUT_TYPE));
        input.setId(R.id.dialog_edit_text);
        input.addTextChangedListener(this);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alert.setCancelable(args.getBoolean(CANCELABLE)).setTitle(args.getInt(TITLE)).setMessage(args.getString(MESSAGE)).setView(input).setPositiveButton(args.getInt(POSITIVE_TEXT), this);
        int negativeText = args.getInt(NEGATIVE_TEXT);
        if (negativeText != 0)
        {
            alert.setNegativeButton(negativeText, this);
        }
        AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
        dialog.setOnShowListener(this);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        // After device rotation there may be some text present.
        if (((EditText)((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.dialog_edit_text)).length() == 0)
        {
            ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        String text = ((EditText)((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.dialog_edit_text)).getText().toString();
        ((Callbacks) getActivity()).onTextViewDialogResult(which, getArguments().getInt(IDENTIFIER), text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        ((Callbacks) getActivity()).onTextViewDialogActivityCancelled(getArguments().getInt(IDENTIFIER));
        super.onCancel(dialog);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(s.length() > 0);
    }

    void setMessage(String message)
    {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        args.putString(MESSAGE, message);
        setArguments(args);
    }

    interface Callbacks
    {
        void onTextViewDialogResult(int which, int identity, String text);
        void onTextViewDialogActivityCancelled(int identity);
    }
}
```

Add implements to your activity (any type of Activity is fine):

```
public class Myctivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextViewDialogFragment.Callbacks
{
...
}
```

Create the diaglogFragment in your activity like this:

```
final static int SOMETHING = 1;
myDF = TextViewDialogFragment.newInstance(R.string.my_title, "my message", SOMETHING, InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES, /* Whatever is best for your user. */    R.string.yay, android.R.string.cancel, true);
```

Handle the result in your activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onTextViewDialogResult(int which, int identity, String text)
{
    if (which == AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
    {
        // User did not want to do anything.
        return;
    }
    // text now holds the users answer.
    // Identity can be used if you use the same fragment for more than one type of question.
}
@Override
public void onTextViewDialogActivityCancelled(int identity)
{
    // This is invoked if you set cancelable to true and the user pressed the back button.
}
```

You need to create the resource identifier so add this resource under somewhere under res/values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="dialog_edit_text" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (editTextEmailAddress.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
    btnCancelCross.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    btnCancelCross.setEnabled(true);
}
```

That might help you thanks.

Comment: thanks but this is not what I am looking for. I can get it done by using custom dialog and create a layout with the button and enable disable them. What I am looking for is that is there a way of disabling or enabling the built in positive and negative buttons of dialog? If you look at the code I shared you will see what I am looking for. But thanks again for the code.

Comment: Please, post _one_ comprehensive on topic answer (just edit your existing answer, don't keep posting additional answers).