# Android disable positive button on some condion in addTextChangedListener (editext)

Tags: android, dialog

Here is my code for a dialog, I want to disable positive button if text size in edit-text  in greater than 5 and enable it if size <= 5

```
private void myDialog(String title) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);


            // Get the layout inflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_dialog, null);

            // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
            builder.setView(dialogView);

            final EditText dialogEdittext = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_editText);
            final TextView dialogMessage = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_limit);

            dialogEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    // if text length is greater than 5 disable positive button
                                // else enable 
                }
            });

            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            });

            final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            dialog.show();

        }
```

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238952/how-to-disable-enable-dialog-negative-possitive-buttons

Comment: i already have seen this link, it will disable/enable button only once when dialog is created, but i want this every time user enter a character in edittext

Comment: I never do by this way. i have did tihs using custom dialog with button and in that check the validation. you can do by that way. try it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     if (s.length() > 5) {
        dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
     } else {
        dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
     }
}
```

where `dialog` is:

```
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: worked but i had to shift  dialogEdittext.addTextChangedListener..... below  ....dialog.show();

Comment: @SyedZahidAli That was required because you declared the `TextWatcher` before the `dialog` variable was created so it couldn't see it.