# How to disable positive and negative button if the checkbox is unchecked in java?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, popup, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to do alert message by disable ok and cancel button if the checkbox is unchecked.

reconfirm.java:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(reconfirm.this);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
                 = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                  .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);


                alertDialogBuilder.setView(popupView);

                CheckBox check= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);  

            if (check.isChecked() ) {

                    AlertDialog dialog = null;
                    ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }




                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                          Intent intObj = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                agree.class);
                        startActivity(intObj);
                      }
                  });


                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                     Intent intObj = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                IntentExampleActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intObj);


                  }

                  });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: pls can you specify your need in details?

Comment: @deniz When I clicked on checkbox "I agre...." the OK and CANCEL will enable. Before that the buttons disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered already here--[How to disable / enable dialog negative positive buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238952/how-to-disable-enable-dialog-negative-possitive-buttons)

after dialog.show use below code

if(your_condition_true)
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON1).setEnabled(false); //BUTTON1 is positive button

Comment: write a checkbox listener (setOnCheckedChangeListener). in it if(isChecked){ dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON1).setEnabled(false);}else { dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON1).setEnabled(true);}

Answer (score 0):

Try Using `setEnabled()` and `setClickable` method for buttons.

here is the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Comment: it just available for API 14. I'm using API 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippets. Hope you get some idea from this :)

```
if (check.isChecked()) {
 alertDialogBuilder.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
 alertDialogBuilder.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setEnabled(false);
}
```

where dialog is object of AlertDialog.

Comment: what is the different between using AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); with final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();?

Comment: @user3714182 I have updated my answer.My intention was to tell that it is object of AlertDialog.I have just answered with reference to your code.Did it worked for u?

Comment: no..i'm tyring to write .setEnabled(false); after the alertDialog.show(); ...there is no error displyed but in the device it show "unfortunately your app has stopped"

Comment: Can u print ur logcat please?