# Android How to disable a positive button after click

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog, builder

I have an information popup which has 2 buttons : Negative (Cancel) and Positive (Continue). How can i disable the positive button after a click. 
The Click on the button generates a file. It calls a function that is quite heavy, so it takes time to close the popup. I am doing this to prevent the user to click twice and thus generate two files.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.close_tour_tour_not_collected);
        builder.setItems(items, null);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.common_continue, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                    int arg1) {     
                    // How to disable the button after the click??? 
                    saveTourAndCloseActivity();
            }

        });
```

Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable / enable dialog negative positive buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238952/how-to-disable-enable-dialog-negative-positive-buttons)

Comment: Just block the saveTourAndCloseActivity() method inside onclick() after clicking

Comment: i hope your answer below link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238952/how-to-disable-enable-dialog-negative-positive-buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238952/how-to-disable-enable-dialog-negative-positive-buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Dialog.class.cast(arg0)).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
```

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240314/5901637)