# How to create and validate a user input prompt box in Android Studio

Tags: android, validation, user-input

I am making a counter. On load or onCreat I want to show an input dialog box for user to input an integer value. **1st...**   If user doesn't enter any character value in box. Then User is not able to click Ok button. **2nd..**  If user doesn't enter any value in it. Then he will not able to hit Ok or Cancle button.

Please help....!!
Thanks in advance

**Here is prompt box code**

```
AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(TasbihWorkActivity.this);
        ab.setTitle("Enter Any String");
        final EditText editText = new EditText(TasbihWorkActivity.this);
        ab.setView(editText);

        ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                count_num.setText(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        ab.setNegativeButton("Cencel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                count_num.setText("No text entered!!!");
            }
        });

        AlertDialog a = ab.create();
        a.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Text Watcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) for your `editText`.  If no input, disable these two button using `setClickable(false);` . If doesn't enter any character value, disable `OK` button

```
    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(TasbihWorkActivity.this);
            ab.setTitle("Enter Any String");
            final EditText editText = new EditText(TasbihWorkActivity.this);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // implement your logic here
    }
});
            ab.setView(editText);

            ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    count_num.setText(editText.getText().toString());
                }
            });

            ab.setNegativeButton("Cencel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    count_num.setText("No text entered!!!");
                }
            });

            AlertDialog a = ab.create();
            a.show();
```

**Edit**

To prevent dialog disappear when screen clicked, add below code

`ab.setCancelable(false)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238952/how-to-disable-enable-dialog-negative-positive-buttons

Comment: No validation on user Input in this one.

Comment: And when user touch on the screen without entering any value the input box disappear. I don't want that the input box disappear.