# How to disable button of a dialog in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have a custom dialog and I want to disable the `PositiveButton` if a specific EditText is empty. I couldn't find how to do that on a dialog.
Here is my code :

```java
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_add_apero, null);

        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Super un nouvel apéro !")
                .setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Ajouter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String titre_apero = editTextApero.getText().toString();
                        String date_apero = editTextDate.getText().toString();
                        listener.applyTexts(titre_apero, date_apero);
                    }
                });

        editTextApero = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_apero);
        editTextDate = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_date);

        return builder.create();
    }
```

So if the field `editTextApero` or `editTextDate` is empty I want to disable the `PositiveButton` or do a pop-up (but it would be a pop-up on a dialog who is also a kind of pop-up) to say that the user has to fill each fields.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238952/how-to-disable-enable-dialog-negative-positive-buttons

Answer (score 2):

Just split the builder expression and add the positive button only if your condition is true.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

if(editTextApero.getText().length() != 0) {
      builder.setPositiveButton("Ajouter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String titre_apero = editTextApero.getText().toString();
                    String date_apero = editTextDate.getText().toString();
                    listener.applyTexts(titre_apero, date_apero);
                }
       });
    }
```

**EDIT** I think this is a possible way:

Set the button disabled to start:

```
((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
```

Then set a text change listener to the EditText:

```
editTextApero.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to make it invisible, use instead:

```
((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and to set back

```
((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: but it won't be dynamic. Like if the user then write how is it going to set it ?

Comment: What triggers the dialog to be created? onCreateDialog() is called the moment you want to show the dialog, right?

Comment: I see, sorry I misunderstood. What if you check in onClick() if EditText has text, and if not, show a toast?

Comment: I'll do that solution